# Application.ProductVersion always returns 1.0.0.0

Tags: vb.net

On the publish tab of My Project the correct current version is there, 1.1.0.0 and in Programs and Features under Control Panel it shows 1.1.0.0 but when I reference Application.ProductVersion I get 1.0.0.0.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The assemby version (in the application.config file) and the ClickOnce Publish version are 2 seperate numbers.

If you want to get the ClickOnce version at runtime you can use the following code

```
     If (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) Then
        With System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
            Me.Text = "V" & .Major & "." & .Minor & "." & .Build
        End With
     End If
```

**Edit:** For the full, four-segment revision number you'll need:

```
Me.Text = "V" & .Major & "." & .Minor & "." & .Build & "." & .Revision
```

Comment: You can only reference those properties if you're running the compiled and deployed version of your app?  What about in the development environment?

Comment: This is why I do the if to start with. Using this method you can't access the Deployment version in dev because it isn't deployed. In our applications I tend to do an else and put in a place holder for in the dev environment.

Comment: So how do you access the same properties but in the development environment?

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to access this in Dev, the ApplicationVersion is stored in the <appname>.application manifest file, so you could always open that and get the version out of there. The other thing to do is query the Assembly using System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() this will list all assemblies so you can iterate through them until you find yours and the version is embedded in the name

Comment: Thanks.  To be honest this all seems unneccesarily complicated to get something so easily visible.  I will deal with it though, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 13):

With `System.Reflection` you can use:

```
Dim versionNumber As Version

versionNumber = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

and then call `.ToString()` on that if needed...

and yet another method is to call

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion
```

(for *Full Disclosure* I found this on [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/141f2920-86b8-4b7a-a4f2-1c3ef71e2af5/how-to-get-application-version-number-in-vbnet-2005?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs))

Comment: This may be the current, modern, easy way to get something that used to be hard to access. In any case, this is the answer that should now be getting upvotes. I tried both suggestions, both worked great. I chose the System. solution since it didn't require an extra Import to make it work (or the ToString either).

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old, but in Visual Studio Express 2013, I ran across the same issue.  I wanted to use variable ProductVersion like so:

```
msgbox (Application.ProductVersion)
```

but it always returned 1.0.0.0 no matter what I put in the settings for Publish.  I found instead I had to put it in Application > Assembly > File Version (I updated both Assembly version and File Version, but it's the File Version that counts).

[image: Application > Assembly > File Version]

You get to this using Project > Properties:

[image: Project Properties]

Now, I only wanted the major and minor numbers (to concatenate to the form title) so I used this:

```
MsgBox(Application.ProductVersion.Substring(0, 3))
```

Hope this helps others.  It was a lot of digging!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should  try to explicitly put an attribute on your assembly:
for example: [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.0.0")]

Regards, Michael.